# Will hibernate work with swap file on 17.04?

Tags: swap

I have checked the past hibernate questions and nothing related to my problem. I have a 1 GB swap file and 16GB memory. When I try doing a hibernate test with `sudo systemctl hibernate` the system doesn't hibernate but does go into a state like an inactive one (I have to put in my password but when I do, everything is still on the screen). I have also done `sudo apt purge btrfs-tools` and have no btrfs file systems. `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` gives me a value of 60.
So do I have to force the swapfile to be at least 16GB for hibernate to work? Note that with 16GB and not doing anything that takes huge amounts of memory, it is unlikely swap is aver used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hibernation (suspend-to-disk)** The hibernation feature (suspend-to-disk) writes out the contents of RAM to the swap partition before turning off the machine. Therefore, your swap partition should be at least as big as your RAM size. The hibernation implementation currently used in Ubuntu, swsusp, needs a swap or suspend partition. **It cannot use a swap file on an active file system.**

ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq